# Compare length of two arrays using C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to compare two integer arrays using C++ if their length is not equal then make those arrays equal to each other by adding items to a smaller-length array. Here is my code snippet.

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
       
        int arrayOne[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        int arrayTwo[] = {8,5,6,4,5,6,4};
        int arrayThree[] = {};
        
        int a = sizeof(arrayOne) / sizeof(int); // 7
        int b = sizeof(arrayTwo) / sizeof(int); // 7
        
 if(a != b){
        if(a > b){ // means b is small 
            int diff = a - b ; // = 2 ... 0,1
            for(int k=0; i < k ; k++ ){ 
                arrayTwo[b+k] = b +k;
            }
        }
        else{
            int diff = b - a ; // = 2 ... 0,1
            for(int k=0; i < k ; k++ ){ 
                arrayOne[b+k] = b +k;
            }
        }
    }
        
        // Here I want to compare these two arrays....
        
        for (int i=0; i < a; i++)
        {
          arrayThree[i] = arrayOne[i] + arrayTwo[i];   // aggregate the sums into the first array
        }
    
        for(int i =0; i < a;i++){
            cout<<arrayThree[i]<<endl;
        }
        
        return 0;
    
    }
```

The main problem I want to sum the item of both arrays so that need to be of the same length.

Comment: And what's your problem?  You're calculating the sizes, so what issue are you having adding the error checking?

Comment: Arrays can't change their size. Consider `std::vector<int>` instead. Oh, btw, also compile with warnings enabled, it should reveal that your code is broken.

Comment: You seem to think that arrays will grow when you assign to them. This is not true, arrays never change their size in C++.

Comment: @KamranKhan You still have the same problem, the smaller array does not grow just because you assign to it. Instead your code is just bugged. It is literally impossible to change the size of an array in C++.

Comment: @KamranKhan Instead you should just use a `std::vector<int>` as already suggested. Vectors can change their size.

Comment: `int arrayThree[] = {};`  in standard C++ you cannot have 0-sized arrays. You were fooled by a compiler extensions that allows to have an array a size of 0, but also with that extension the size of the array is fixed (to 0)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/WTPj9Ydv5

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But its working

Comment: no it is not working. Your code doesnt even compile (also without the pedentic flag, there are errors). And if you get it to compile, accessing an array out of bounds is still undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means anything can happen, including: It appears to work, when actually it does not

Comment: arrays cannot change their size. Its as simple as that. If you do want a dynamically sized array use `std::vector`. If C++ made a poor choice with `vector` because it isnt acutally modelling a vector in the mathematical sense, then other langauges made a poor choice with calling dynamically sized data structures `Array`

Comment: It is working does not mean it is not bugged. This is unfortunate, and it takes a while for newbies to realise the truth of this, but it is true. Any code which accesses an array outside of it's declared bounds is bugged.

Comment: I have debugged it and also run it and it gives me the output

Comment: @KamranKhan -- *I have debugged it and also run it and it gives me the output* -- Welcome to the world of C++, where undefined behavior occurs.  Do you mean the same code you posted, it gave you the output?  Well, as others mentioned, you've been fooled into thinking you have a working program.  Your program is broken, plain and simple.  Also: `for(int k=0; i < k ; k++ ){ ` where was `i` declared?  This code doesn't compile.

Comment: @KamranKhan If you don't believe your program is broken, compile with `-fsanitize=address,undefined` and it will show where it is broken and how it is broken.

Comment: @KamranKhan *I have debugged it and also run it and it gives me the output* -- If you plugged a faulty iron into a wall socket, the iron turns on, smoke starts to come out of the wires, but you are able to iron your clothes, do you say the iron is ok?  That's what you are dealing with -- a broken program that you are claiming "works" because you see the final results.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot increase or decrease size of the array because it is static.
You can compare two array by size only. For increasing or decreasing size and adding the element you can use vector.